# Insert failed: datatype mismatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xml-parsing, sqlite

When I am showing my data in NSLog, it is showing properly. But when I am parsing the data & inserting it in an array, the array is showing wrong ordered data. While I'm iserting I'm getting null value in **HNM_Id**. So I am not able to insert. Where is the problem?

This is the code I am using:

```
-(void)parseResponse:(NSData*)data{
   NSString *xmlStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"parseResponse Xml string %@",xmlStr);

    [sqliteManager deleteLoginDetails];

    TBXMLEx *xml = [TBXMLEx parserWithXML:xmlStr];


      if (xml.rootElement) {


        TBXMLElementEx *returnNode = xml.rootElement;

        TBXMLElementEx *fileNode = [returnNode child:@"AllHospitalNetwork"];

        while ([fileNode next]) {
            NSMutableArray* allHospitalNetwork = [NSMutableArray new];

            TBXMLElementEx *hospitalNetworkNode = [fileNode child:@"HospitalNetwork"];

            while ([hospitalNetworkNode next]) {
                NSMutableDictionary* hospitalNetwork = [NSMutableDictionary new];

                TBXMLElementEx *HNM_IdNode = [hospitalNetworkNode child:@"HNM_ID"];

                NSLog(@"HNM is %@",HNM_IdNode);

                if (HNM_IdNode) {
                    [hospitalNetwork setObject:HNM_IdNode.value forKey:@"HNM_ID"];

                    NSLog(@"HNM1 is %@",HNM_IdNode);

                    NSLog(@"HNM2 is %@",HNM_IdNode.value);
                }

                TBXMLElementEx *HNM_Network_NameNode = [hospitalNetworkNode child:@"HNM_Network_Name"];

                if (HNM_Network_NameNode) {
                    [hospitalNetwork setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",HNM_Network_NameNode.value] forKey:@"HNM_Network_Name"];
                }

                TBXMLElementEx *HNM_StatusNode = [hospitalNetworkNode child:@"HNM_Status"];

                if (HNM_StatusNode) {
                    [hospitalNetwork setObject:HNM_StatusNode.value forKey:@"HNM_Status"];
                }

                TBXMLElementEx *HNM_Created_DateNode = [hospitalNetworkNode child:@"HNM_Created_Date"];

                if (HNM_Created_DateNode) {
                    [hospitalNetwork setObject:HNM_Created_DateNode.value forKey:@"HNM_Created_Date"];
                }

                TBXMLElementEx *HNM_Created_ByNode = [hospitalNetworkNode child:@"HNM_Created_By"];

                if (HNM_Created_ByNode) {
                    [hospitalNetwork setObject:HNM_Created_ByNode.value forKey:@"HNM_Created_By"];
                }

                TBXMLElementEx *HNM_Modified_DateNode = [hospitalNetworkNode child:@"HNM_Modified_Date"];

                if (HNM_Created_ByNode) {
                    [hospitalNetwork setObject:HNM_Modified_DateNode.value forKey:@"HNM_Modified_Date"];
                }

                TBXMLElementEx *HNM_Modified_ByNode = [hospitalNetworkNode child:@"HNM_Modified_By"];

                if (HNM_Modified_ByNode) {
                    [hospitalNetwork setObject:HNM_Modified_ByNode.value forKey:@"HNM_Modified_By"];
                }

                [allHospitalNetwork addObject:hospitalNetwork];


                NSLog(@"allHospitalNetwork insert is %@ ",allHospitalNetwork);

            } 
                [sqliteManager insertHospitalNetwork:allHospitalNetwork];


        }
```

parseResponse Xml string NSLog:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AllLoginDetails>
  <AllHospitalNetwork>
    <HospitalNetwork>
      <HNM_ID>1</HNM_ID>
      <HNM_Network_Name>Health Care</HNM_Network_Name>
      <HNM_Status>A</HNM_Status>
      <HNM_Created_Date>24/06/2013 17:46:58</HNM_Created_Date>
      <HNM_Created_By>1</HNM_Created_By>
      <HNM_Modified_Date />
      <HNM_Modified_By />
    </HospitalNetwork>
    </AllHospitalNetwork>
```

But Array value order changed:

```
allHospitalNetwork insert is (
        {
        "HNM_Created_By" = 1;
        "HNM_Created_Date" = "24/06/2013 17:46:58";
        "HNM_ID" = 1;
        "HNM_Modified_By" = "";
        "HNM_Modified_Date" = "";
        "HNM_Network_Name" = "Health Care";
        "HNM_Status" = A;
    }
```

Insert :

```
-(void)insertHospitals:(NSMutableArray*)hospitals{

 NSString* sqlStr = @"insert into Hospital_Master(\"HM_ID\",\"HM_HNM_ID\",\"HM_Hospital_Name\",\"HM_Status\",\"HM_Created_Date\",\"HM_Created_By\",\"HM_Modified_Date\",\"HM_Modified_By\")";


    for (NSDictionary* feedDict in hospitals) {
        if(i > 0){
            sqlStr = [sqlStr stringByAppendingString:@" UNION "];


        }


     sqlStr = [sqlStr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" SELECT \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\"",[feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Id"] ,[feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_HNM_Id"],[feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Hospital_Name"], [feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Status"], [feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Created_Date"],[feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Created_By"],[feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Modified_Date"],[feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Modified_By"]]];


        i++;

    }

    char * sql =sqlite3_mprintf("%q",[sqlStr UTF8String]);

 sqlite3_exec(database, sql, 0, 0, 0);

    NSLog(@"Insert failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_free(sql);
}
```

Insert failed: datatype mismatch

Answer (score 0):

you are using much tough way to do this insertion task, actually i cant get completely what are u doing but i m providing u a following template for insertion purpose..

here in your code, you are not preparing the query statement, you are directly executing query, so first you should prepare statement correctly and latter you can execute it...

Here is the template,

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into table_name (col_name_1, col_name_2, col_name_3) values(\"%@\",\"%d\",\"%d\")",variable_vale_1, variable_vale_2, variable_vale_3];
// Here i m assuming that first value is NSString type and other are integer type
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_object, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Statement is Failed.....");
    }
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Don't forget to finalize your statement and be careful while providing datatypes of entities.

Just arrange your code using this template, i hope it will work for you...

Answer (score -1):

I dont know which language is this,

But try using the below code in place, where you are creating the SQL query.

`sqlStr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" SELECT '%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@'",[feedDict objectForKey:@"HM_Id"] ,......`